# Autohotkey Run, escaping () in path

Tags: escaping, autohotkey

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to escape this such that it will work. Here is the basic command that needs escaping:

`Run, "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`

I tried adding backticks but it just doesn't work.

```
Run, "%ProgramFiles`(x86`)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
Run, "`%ProgramFiles`(x86`)`%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

The only thing that I can get to work is to escape it all the way so that I can run it with cmd /c. But the following snippet also runs a cmd window and keeps it open until I close VS, which is obviously not ideal...

```
Run, cmd /C "`"`%ProgramFiles`(x86`)`%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`""
```

Does anyone know the correct way to get this done? It seems to support environment variables, but if it contains (), I can't get it to work no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`EnvGet`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/EnvGet.htm) to get the value of an enviroment variable and store it in a new variable.

```
; Move the contents of 'ProgramFile(x86)' into programFiles_x86
EnvGet, programFiles_x86, ProgramFiles(x86)

msgBox % programFiles_x86
Run, %programFiles_x86%
```